# onUnLoad при закрытии окна

Tags: javascript

Сделал простенькую страницу как в примере, при открытие которой выводиться сообщение "привет" а при закрытии окна сделал вывод сообщения "пока".

При открытие всё нормально, сообщение выводиться, а вот при закрытии окна, сообщение никак выводиться не хочет.

я пробовал два примера:

```
<body onLoad="vhod()" onUnLoad="vihod()">

<body onLoad="vhod()" onUnload="vihod()">
```

Ни одно из этих решений не действенно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
funcction loadPage() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {alert("пока");}
    alert("Привет");
}
//

<body onload="loadPage()">
```

Внимательнее с регистром!

Comment: По моему данный код даже не во всех браузерах работает. Если не так - то поправьте.

Comment: @lampa, всё [так](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror#window-onbeforeunload "Событие onbeforeunload"). Не работает в Opera и надо использовать по другому но я думаю @Роман и сам почитает как...